# How to use locomotive scroll in Angular

Tags: angular, locomotive-scroll

Is there a way to use Locomotive scroll in angular. I didn't find anything about this on google. Has somebody ever use Locomotive scroll in angular?

I tried to import it in my homepage.component.ts :

```
import {Component, HostListener, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import LocomotiveScroll from 'locomotive-scroll';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-homepage',
  templateUrl: './homepage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./homepage.component.css']
})
export class HomepageComponent implements OnInit {
  scroll;

  constructor() {

  }

  @HostListener('window:load')
  initLocomotiveScroll() {
    this.scroll = new LocomotiveScroll({
      el: document.querySelector('[data-scroll-container]'),
      smooth: true,
    });
  }

}
```

homepage.componenet.html :

```
<div data-scroll-container style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
  <div data-scroll-section>
    <h1 data-scroll>Hey</h1>
    <p data-scroll></p>
  </div>
  <div data-scroll-section>
    <h2 data-scroll data-scroll-speed="1">What's up?</h2>
    <p data-scroll data-scroll-speed="2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank's in advance.

Jérémy.

Comment: What is locomotive scroll?

Comment: It's a library to create scroll effects : https://locomotivemtl.github.io/locomotive-scroll/

Comment: It's a simple js library. Why can't you just import it and use it as it is ? If you tried something that doesn't work please show us what you did

Comment: I imported it in my homepage.component.ts

Comment: Maybe create a small example (stackblitz or other) reproducing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Locomotive Scroll has to know about your content height in order to work correct. To solve the issue, call the update method of Locomotive Scroll whenever your content is rendered or changed. This can be done by using Locomotive Scroll's .update() function.

As outlined in this tutorial you can use a resize observer to automate the update function call: https://flo-lech.medium.com/using-locomotive-scroll-with-angular-a5e9049233dd

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is the *strict* attribute.

**FIX tsconfig.json**

Set the strict attribute in the *tsconfing.json* file to false

```
 "strict": false
```

This worked for me!